# Pass data from component to action and saga using ARc/React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm using https://arc.js.org/ to setup a new project and am confused on how data is passed about. I'm just using a form to post some login data and can't seem to get the data to the post itself in my actions/sagas (meaning, my login form component has the data and tries to send it on, but after dispatching the action, value is undefined).

Intending to get the form values into redux store (updating onChange to be accessible onSubmit, not passing up as I am now), but wanted to get this version working first and then move on to that so I know what's actually happening.

Let me know if missing necessary info here.

LoginFormContainer:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { userLoginRequest } from 'store/actions'
import { fromUser } from 'store/selectors'
import { LoginForm } from 'components'

class LoginFormContainer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const serialize = new FormData(event.target)
    const loginData = {
      email: serialize.get('email'),
      password: serialize.get('password'),
    }
    this.props.login(loginData)
  }

  render() {
    return <LoginForm handleSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: fromUser.getUser(state),
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, { loginData }) => ({
  login: () => dispatch(userLoginRequest(loginData)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginFormContainer)
```

LoginFormComponent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import { Field } from 'components'

const Form = styled.form`
  width: 100%;
`

const LoginForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        label="Email"
        name="email"
        type="text"
      />
      <Field
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        type="text"
      />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </Form>
  )
}

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default LoginForm
```

Actions:

```
export const USER_LOGIN_REQUEST = 'USER_LOGIN_REQUEST'
export const USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS'
export const USER_LOGIN_FAILURE = 'USER_LOGIN_FAILURE'

// This doesn't know what data is (undefined)
export const userLoginRequest = (data, resolve, reject) => ({
  type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  data,
  resolve,
  reject,
})

export const userLoginSuccess = detail => ({
  type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  detail,
})

export const userLoginFailure = error => ({
  type: USER_LOGIN_FAILURE,
  error,
})
```

Sagas:

```
import { take, put, call, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import api from 'services/api'
import * as actions from './actions'

// This doesn't know what loginData is (undefined)
export function* login(loginData) {
  try {
    const encoded = window.btoa(`${loginData.email}:${loginData.password}`)
    const data = yield call(api.post, '/login', { Authorization: `Basic ${encoded}` })
    yield put(actions.userLoginSuccess(data))
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(actions.userLoginFailure(e))
  }
}
export function* watchUserLoginRequest() {
  while (true) {
    const { data } = yield take(actions.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST)
    yield call(login, data)
  }
}

export default function* () {
  yield fork(watchUserLoginRequest)
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(serialize)` in onSubmit?

Comment: loginData and serialize are good - when this.props.login is called it knows what it is (which is {email: "asdfasf", password: "asfsf"}). Then past that it just goes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: in your mapDispatchProps second params you decompose loginData. It should not be decomposed, should it?

Comment: It should NOT, mixed examples code up. Thanks so much for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @dagatsoin for helping lead in right direction!

mapDispatchToProps should be:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  login: (loginData) => dispatch(userLoginRequest(loginData)),
})
```